# Embed string containing HTML in React safely

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using the library linkifyjs, which parses a comment and returns the string with an `<a>` tag of the text if it contains a link. This is cool, but the only way I know to use this would be `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. I'm fleshing out the comment system from the React tutorial, so I feel using my current method would leave it susceptible to injected scripts.

Is there anyway I can convert a string to an HTML element and safely embed it?

Edit: Forgot to elaborate, I am pulling comments from Facebook which would return a plain string, "visit stackoverflow.com today".

Comment: Could always set a ref on the node you wish to insert to, and use standard dom methods like appendChild() to append the actual tag object to it.

Comment: A rich editor like draftjs can be used to display articles, comments, etc.

Comment: @Vijay My apologies, I am pulling comments from Facebook as well. I will investigate that package for posting purposes. Thank you!